# How to have bean of repository interface of spring data jpa during run of test cases

Tags: spring, junit, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

We have written below 2 classes

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
public class AbcFilterTest {

    @Autowired
    private AbcUtils abcUtils;

    @Autowired
    private AbcRepository abcRepository;

    @Test
    public void testFilter() {

        MockHttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        MockHttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        MockFilterChain mockChain = new MockFilterChain();

    }
}

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {AbcUtils.class, AbcRepository.class,})
    public class TestConfig {
    }
```

For running a test class, i need instance of both AbcUtilsclass and AbcRepository interface(extending CurdRepository) which are autowired in the class i am testing.1st one has @Component while 2nd has @Repositry on top of it.As you can see,in my test class I have autowired both util and repository class with component scan as above code.In real time spring framework creates implementaion class for the repository interface but On running test case,I am getting below error

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate [com.a.b.c.persistence.AbcRepository]: Specified
>   class is an interface.

Kindly suggest how to make this test class work. Please note that we are not using Spring Boot and Mockito.We are doing integration testing.
We are using Spring rest and Spring Data JPA with hibernate.

Comment: I think you will need to post your config file TestConfig.class, as we don't see anywhere in your code where you are telling Spring you are going to use Spring Data JPA. Or are you using Spring Boot? Just make sure you remove any passwords or private info you might have in your test config.

Comment: AbcRepository is an interface, you can't treat it as a class

Comment: You need to extend `AbcRepository` with some JPA implementation, or write custom implementation of this interface.

Answer (score -1):

Scanning `AbcUtils.class` and `AbcRepository.class` is not enough if you want to write something in the database. You need to scan the configuration that contains your DataSource definition and related config. Since the tests will be instantiated like a Spring bean too, the test class need to implement the ApplicationContextAware interface:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/config.xml"}) 
public class TestClass implements ApplicationContextAware{
  @Autowired
  Repository repository;
//....
}
```